# stuck in regular expression i dont know if it is even possible or not using php preg_match_all

Tags: php, regex, expression, pcre, preg-match-all

i have a file out of which i want a specific data below is the sample data

```
 moduleHelper.addModule('REC');
  moduleHelper.addModule('TOP');
```

What i want is

> anything.anything('x');i.e.

```
moduleHelper.addModule('');
```

The above is what i want to be returned .

i just dont want the 'x' part exclusive of single quote.

i tried by my self and wrote a regex which is below.

> `/(.*)\.(.*)\(\'[^.*]\'\)/mi`

it gives me nothing according to the PCRE manual the ^ inside the [ ] does negation ??

Comment: `/(.*)\.(.*)\(\'?[^.*]\'?\)/mi` ?

Comment: Do you mean you want to replace x by an empty string?

Comment: He means that the quotes around `x` might be single or double or whatever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be done with [preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) if you feel like figuring out how all that backreferencing works, but i think this is a bit easier:

```
// the regex
$regex = "/(?P<FIRST>.+)?\.(?P<SECOND>.+)\('(?P<PARAM>.+)?\'\)?/mi";

$subject = <<<EOB
moduleHelper.addModule('REC');
moduleHelper.addModule('TOP');
EOB;

$matches = array();
$numberOfMatches = preg_match_all($regex, $subject, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);


$results = array();
foreach($matches as $match)
{
    array_push($results, sprintf("%s.%s('')", $match['FIRST'], $match['SECOND']));
}

print_r($results);

// result:

Array
(
    [0] => moduleHelper.addModule('')
    [1] => moduleHelper.addModule('')
)
```

Answer (score 0):

It does do negation. `[^.*]`, in this case, means "get on character that is **not** `.` or `*`. I think you want below, but I can't totally tell.

```
preg_match_all( "/(\w+\.\w+)(?=\([\"']\w+[\"']\);)/i", $string, $matches);
```

Comment: thanks Kevin, i want everthing except the parameter going inside the function. your pattern works ok but i don't want the parameter part to returned i want moduleHelper.addModule('');

Comment: @G molvi, I've updated my regex. This will get you `moduleHelper.addModule` from anything that has a object + method call and one parameter.

Comment: Thanks kevin you are very close it is giving me moduleHelper.addModule thats it i want it to give me moduleHelper.addModule('');

Comment: @G molvi, that's the closest you will get w/o also getting the parameter. Just append `('')` to the results you get. If you are specifically trying to match `moduleHelper.addModule('');` add `\(''\(` to the end of the regex.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following

```
/^([^.]+)\.([^\(]+)/
```

Answer (score 0):

If ^ is the first character in [ ] then it negates the other characters in the set. Where [ab] accepts either a or b, [^ab] accepts any character that is not a nor b.

Also I'm not sure what you want. You state that you do not want the 'x', but what exactly do you want?

Comment: i want the line with out the parameter name goin inside that function

Comment: If you use `preg_match` then `/(.+\..+\(\').*(\'\))/Ui` should give you the first part (up to and including `'` in `$matches[1]` and the closing `')` in `$matches[2]`. This of course means you need to specify the third parameter of `preg_match`. I don't think it's possible to get what you want in one string, you have to use string concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
 /([^.]*)\.([^.]*)\(.*\)/
```

Comment: sorry it is still the same as before